# VBA returning a value and error information together

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am writing some VBA in MS Access, although the principle of my question would apply just as well to Excel or Word VBA. I have written a function GetStringParameterFromTable which returns a string value. It is possible that the function may result in a VBA-generated error, despite my best efforts to write it so that it does not. If an error happens, I don't want the code to crash, so I must use error handling. However, I don't want the code to display an error message and stop within the function if there is an error. I want the function to finish executing and return control to the calling procedure, and then I want the calling procedure to display the error message and tidy up, e.g. close open files. My question is: how does the calling procedure know that there has been an error in the function it called, and how does it get the error message?

I have thought of three ways of implementing this:

(1) Make GetStringParameterFromTable into a Sub, and pass it ParameterValue, ErrorFlag and ErrorMessage by reference.

(2) Keep GetStringParameterFromTable as a Function, define ErrorFlag and ErrorMessage as global variables and have the function alter ErrorFlag and ErrorMessage.

(3) Keep GetStringParameterFromTable as a Function and define a type with three components – ParameterValue, ErrorFlag and ErrorMessage – and make GetStringParameterFromTable return a value of the type I have defined.

I think that my requirement must be quite common, but I can’t find any examples of how it’s implemented. Does anyone have any views on which of my suggestions is the best way, or whether there is a better way that I haven’t thought of?

Comment: Throw the error. That's what errors are meant for. If you need to clean up in the calling function, catch it. That's what error handlers are meant for. "Returning" an error condition as a value simply confuses the roles of a return value and an exception.

Comment: Regarding those errors, does VBA or the db engine recognize them as errors?

Comment: @Comintern thank you. Can you explain what you mean by "Throw the error"? And how I would catch it in the calling function?

Comment: @HansUp thank you. Not sure what you mean. The VBA stops with an error message if I don't handle the error.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood then.  But when `DLookup` can't find the value you're looking for, it doesn't throw an error ... it simply returns Null.  I don't understand why that should be called an error.  It might be clearer if you show a simplified version of your function which demonstrates the type of thing you want to deal with.

Comment: Ah, OK. I also want to handle the case where the table doesn't exist because someone's deleted or renamed it, or when the column doesn't exist. Just make the code more robust and helpful to the user if it goes wrong. Anyway, I would like to know generally about how a sub or function can tell the calling routine that there has been an error, but not immediately terminate the program.

Comment: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/).

Comment: @Zajonc -  Your questions needs examples of your code and data if you want an answer - you have us making blind guesses what your problem is.  I'm thinking that maybe you are getting an error, from not properly handing `DLookup`'s `Null` return value.  If so, you could use something like `If IsNull(DLookup("yourField1","yourTable","yourField2=" & yourValue))`.  Please see how to create a [mcve] as well as "[ask]". You can always [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: I have been contemplating the same thing since C#.net has implemented Tuples.  I have implemented Tuples using VBA's `type` to create my tuples.  For example `type myTuple

Comment: @Comintern you have answered my question in your comments. I see that the fundamental misconception I had was that the On Error statement is valid only for the procedure you put it in. In fact, if you call another sub or function from the procedure, the On Error persists. Other commenters got hung up on Dlookup, which was not the point of the question - it was about error handling when calling a function generally.

Comment: @Zajonc ***You*** answered your question - I just pointed you in the right direction.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have been contemplating the same thing since C#.net has implemented Tuples.  I have implemented Tuples using VBA's `type` to create my tuples. What I have done is the following:

```
Public Type myTuple
    Value as String 'Or whatever type your value needs to be
    ErrCode as Long
    ErrDesc as String
End Type

Public Function DoWork (ByRef mObject as MyClass) as myTuple
    Dim retVal as myTuple

    'Do whatever work
    If Err.Number <> 0 then
       retVal.Value = Nothing
       retVal.ErrNumber = Err.Number
       retVal.ErrDesc = Err.Description
    Else
       Set retVal.Value = Whatever Makes Sense
       retVal.ErrNumber = 0
       retVal.ErrDesc = VbNullString
    End If
    DoWork = retVal
End Function
```

I would like to be more specific, but you didn't provide a code example.

Comment: Thank you Jamie for this. This is exactly the sort of thing I had in mind in one of my solutions, but I now see that VBA's error handling will work for me without doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing it like this and log the errors in a table:

```
' Lookups Replacements
'---------------------

Function DLook(Expression As String, Domain As String, Optional Criteria) As Variant

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT " & Expression & " FROM " & Domain 'DLookup
'DCount: strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
'DMax: strSQL = "SELECT MAX(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
'DMin: strSQL = "SELECT SUM(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
'DFirst: strSQL = "SELECT FIRST(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
'DLast: strSQL = "SELECT LAST(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
'DSum: strSQL = "SELECT SUM(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
'DAvg: strSQL = "SELECT AVG(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain

If Not IsMissing(Criteria) Then strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & Criteria
DLook = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenForwardOnly)(0)

Exit Function

Err_Handler:
  'Can be made as Error Sub as well
  Dim ErrNumber as Integer
  Dim ErrDescription as String
  ErrNumber = Err.Number
  ErrDescription = Err.Description
  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim strSQL as String
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblErrorLog (ErrorNumber, ErrorDescription) VALUES (" & ErrNumber & ", '" & ErrDescription & "')"
  Currentdb.Excecute strSQL, dbFailOnError

End Function
```

Called with:

```
If DLook("Column2", "Table1", "Column1 = " & ID) = 0 Then
'Do stuff
End If

If DLook("Column2", "Table1") = 0 Then
 'Do other stuff
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Strawberryshrub. I have also been using a log table for errors and it is very useful. I wanted to use something more immediately accessible as well.